# ¿ Cómo girar un objeto paralelo al eje y que sea paralelo al eje x?

Tags: c#, unity3d, objeto

Tengo un GameObject que funciona como generador de objetos y se generan según el eje y, es decir, rectos, según esta función:

```
public void Generar() {

    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    InvokeRepeating ("Generar", 3, 180);
}
```

¿ Cómo puedo hacer para que salgan paralelos al eje x ? Ya he puesto en el generador los objetos que se tienen que generar en la forma correcta, paralelas al eje x, pero me salen como antes, por qué? he intentado poner en la función anterior `transform.position.x` pero me sale error.

Comment: hablas de la rotación?

Comment: Sí, hablo de la rotacion

Comment: Lo resolviste? has intentado con `Quaternion.identity` o tambien con lookAt como en este ejemplo: `Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], transform.position, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.up));` en la [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien esto es algo confuso -> *¿ Cómo girar un objeto paralelo al eje y que sea paralelo al eje x?*, y el codigo que muestra, "pero" quizas soy yo, pero mirando su codigo y esta otra parte -> *¿ Cómo puedo hacer para que salgan paralelos al eje x ?* le dejare algun codigo para que determine o entienda lo que hacen, espero sea lo que pregunta.

---

si entiendo bien su pregunta usted quiere instanciarlo en el eje x, pero usted le esta pasando como vector de posicion, la posicion del objeto que tiene el script, de esta manera -> `transform.position`, me imagino que por el nombre de la clase, quizas sea un objeto dummy que tendra por la escena, aun no teniendo ningun modelo asociado "mesh", este tiene un transform, de ahi que pueda hacer -> transform.position, bien esto funciona pero esta tomando la posicion en el espacio donde tenga el objeto que tiene el script, asi que se instanciara en esa posicion:

```
    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], transform.position,
                 Quaternion.identity);
```

Ahora trate de usar `Vector3.right` lo que lo instaciara en la posicion `x + 1` en relacion con el espacio, pues me imagino que el movimiento para este obejeto sera controlado por el script de el objeto en cuestion osea el que esta instanciando o desde otro lugar.

```
    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], Vector3.right,
                Quaternion.identity);
```

Aun asi si la instanciacion no tiene la rotacion que espera en base, al modelo original, puede usar lo que comenta [Arie CwHat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63678/c%C3%B3mo-girar-un-objeto-paralelo-al-eje-y-que-sea-paralelo-al-eje-x/66160#comment-115729), sobre el uso de `Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.up)` intente con eso ademas de lo anterior `Vector3.right`.

```
    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], Vector3.right,
                 Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.up));
```

Usted dice *...Ya he puesto en el generador los objetos que se tienen que generar en la forma correcta, paralelas al eje x...* - donde lo a puesto.

Supongamos que tiene algo asi:

```
    //esto puede ser una simulacion de lo que usted dice que ha puesto.
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
```

Pues lo usamos asi:

```
    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], pos,
                 Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.up));
```

Pues como se dijo antes con `transform.position` se le esta pasando la posicion del objeto que tiene el script, pero si usted solo quiere tomar la posicion del objeto que tiene el script pero solo en la `x` de este, puede trata algo asi:

```
    Vector3 solo_x = Vector3.zero; 
    solo_x.x = transform.position.x;

    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], solo_x, 
                 Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.up));

    InvokeRepeating ("Generar", 3, 180);
```

---

Notese el cambio de `transform,position` por otros `Vector3`.

---

Por otro lado si lo que usted quiere es controlar la rotacion con la que se instancia el objeto puede tratar algo asi:

```
    Vector3 solo_x = Vector3.zero; 
    solo_x.x = transform.position.x;

    //esta es la rotacion en la que queremos que se instancie, puede modificarla y ajustarla
    //asiganmos la rotacion que queremos atravez de un Vector3
    Vector3 rotar_y = new Vector3 (0, 90, 0);

    Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0,obj.Length)], solo_x, Quaternion.Euler(rotar_y.x, rotar_y.y, rotar_y.z));
    InvokeRepeating ("Generar", 3, 180);
```

---

En lo anterior usamos `Vector3 rotar_y` para asignara la rotacion en base a Euler<sup>1</sup>

Pero [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) requiere un `Quaternion` para la rotacion asi que podemos usar [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) de la siguiente manera,

```
Quaternion.Euler(rotar_y.x, rotar_y.y, rotar_y.z);
```

para obtener un `Quaternion` que es lo que usamos en el metodo [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) visto en el codigo anteriormente:

<sup>1</sup>

> Los ángulos de Euler constituyen un conjunto de tres coordenadas
>   angulares que sirven para especificar la orientación de un sistema de
>   referencia de ejes ortogonales, normalmente móvil, respecto a otro
>   sistema de referencia de ejes ortogonales normalmente fijos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tus respuestas tan completas, +1 por ellas Angel, grande. Por cierto, pasate por una pregunta que voy a formular ahora que es como